XAMPP, Microsoft PHP Drivers for SQL Server Support: cannot find the extensions
I'm having a problem setting up a server using XAMPP.
After setting up everything, PHP throws an error saying that Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect(), after some more troubleshooting I found out that PHP couldn't find the extensions. My PHP version is 8.0.3 (BTW when I ran php --version I got this:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_sqlsrv_83_ts_x64' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_sqlsrv_83_ts_x64 (Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_sqlsrv_83_ts_x64.dll (Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_sqlsrv_83_ts_x64' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_sqlsrv_83_ts_x64 (Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_sqlsrv_83_ts_x64.dll (Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pdo_sqlsrv_83_ts_x64' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_83_ts_x64 (Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_pdo_sqlsrv_83_ts_x64.dll (Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pdo_sqlsrv_83_ts_x64' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_83_ts_x64 (Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_pdo_sqlsrv_83_ts_x64.dll (Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 8.0.30 (cli) (built: Sep  1 2023 14:15:38) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.30, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies

The extensions are there:

As well as activated in the right php.ini file:

My extension dir:
extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"
EDIT: I noticed I installed the wrong modules version, so I changed it from the 83 version to the 80 version. Now the errors are gone, but this error still remains Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect().

You also need to install the appropriate ODBC driver. An old question and answers, but the steps are the same.

I had it already installed, I reinstalled it anyway, but no luck.

Are you actually using the thread-safe version of PHP?

@C3roe Yes. Thread Safety enabled

Well, I found out I've installed the wrong version of the modules. Since I had PHP 8.0.3 I had to install the version 80 modules. Anyways, I get no errors, but sqlsrv won't popup in phpinfo().

Try adding .dll in php.ini

There was a whole list of problems:

First of all, wrong modules version installed. Since I had PHP 8.0.3 I had to import the 80 version of the modules, but instead I installed the 83.
Second, didn't include php8ts.php.
Third, after changing the modules, their name changed too, and the filenames specified in the php.ini wouldn't match what it actually had.

